# Create custom UITableViewCell with sliding object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am in need of creating my own custom `UITableViewCell`. Within each cell, I want to have a view which is a switch. The switch is going to have a label on it and the users are supposed to be able to swipe right to move the switch to the right and swipe left to move the switch to the left. I have drawn a very simple prototype picture which you can see here: [Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvJK9.jpg) (Basically the blue part is supposed to be moved right and left with swipes)

[image]
[image]

I have managed to do it in a simple way. Creating a view, containing another square view, adding a gesture to this view and then move it using animation.

The problem is that if I try to add this view to the custom `UITableViewCell`, nothing happens.

Any tips or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: post the code where you add it to the table view

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" -- does the view not show up? Or just not respond?

UIViews need userInteractionEnabled to be true

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this view to the cell through

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Within this method do something like the following:

```
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

 UIView *customView = (UIView *) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    customView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
    //Bla Bla Bla

return cell;

}
```

If you are using storyboard, which I am assuming you are, make sure to add the customIdentifier to the cell as well, in this case "customCell". Do so by clicking on the cell and simply typing in the id.

If that still does not work, ensure you have all your delegates hooked up correctly in your code and storyboard, ensure your tableview is linked etc.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to accomplish this. One way is to give your blue view 0 spacing constraints to the left and right side of the superview, and give the left one a priority of 750, and the right one a priority of 749. Then give the blue view a width constraint that's half the width of its superview (in IB at a least, Xcode won't let you make this width constraint between the blue view and the contentView of the cell -- you have to add another view first that is pinned to all sides of the content view, and make the blue view a subview of that full sized view). This setup will give you blue views that are half the width of the cell, and pinned, initially to the left side.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you would set the position of the "switch" by changing the priority of one of those constraints (I chose the trailing constraint, which I made an IBOutlet to). Whichever constraint (leading or trailing) has the higher priority is the one that will be satisfied. The gesture recognizer's action method needs to replace the priority value with a new one, and then animate the switch's position. Here is sample code that I used to test this setup,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = [@[@749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749, @749] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.rightSwiper addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    [cell.leftSwiper addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    cell.trailingCon.priority = [self.theData[indexPath.row] floatValue];
    return cell;
}


-(void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) swiper {
    CGPoint point = [swiper.view convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    RDTableViewCell *cell = (RDTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    if (swiper.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        [self.theData replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:@749];
    }else{
        [self.theData replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:@751];
    }

    cell.trailingCon.priority = [self.theData[path.row] floatValue];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
}
```